# Shell script to make many directories

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a file hierarchy to store data. I want to create a folder for each data acquisition session. That folder has five subfolders, which are named below. My code attempt below gives an error, but I'm not sure how to correct it.

**Code**

```
 #!/bin/sh
 TRACES = "/Traces"
 LFPS = '/LFPS'
 ANALYSIS = '/Analysis' 
 NOTES = '/Notes'
 SPIKES = '/Spikes'

 folders=($TRACES $LFPS $ANALYSIS $NOTES $SPIKES)
 for folder in "${folders[@]}"
  do
    mkdir $folder
  done
```

**Error**
I get an error when declaring the variables. As written above, `bash` flips the error `Command not found`. If, instead, I declare the file names as `TRACES = $('\Traces')`, `bash` flips the error `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Error is because of spaces (see answers below). You don't need a loop: Just `mkdir "${folders[@]}"` is fine. Use more quotes. I don't get the point of defining all these variables anyway. Be careful, these folders will be created in the root of the file system, which is a very bad idea.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I intended to modify the path. I just shortened it for the purposes of the question. I'm defining the variables because I'm doing PhD research and my supervisor wants folders named a certain way. (sigh)

Comment: To answer your question "Why do I get an error", it's because of the whitespaces in the assignments which should read as `TRACES="/Traces"`. Apart from this, you code should work. Please use `mkdir "$folder"` (with the double quotes `"`) in your loop, just in case you have spaces in your paths (and if you claim you don't have spaces, just put the quotes anyway, it's the best habit you can get when programming bash). Also, please write `folders=("$TRACES" "$LFPS" "$ANALYSIS" "$NOTES" "$SPIKES")` with quotes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the spaces between the variable names and the values:

```
#!/bin/sh
TRACES="/Traces"
LFPS='/LFPS'
ANALYSIS='/Analysis' 
NOTES='/Notes'
SPIKES='/Spikes'

folders=($TRACES $LFPS $ANALYSIS $NOTES $SPIKES)
for folder in "${folders[@]}"
 do
   mkdir $folder
 done
```

With spaces, `bash` interprets this like

```
COMMAND param1 param2
```

with `=` as `param1`

Answer (score 5):

I'm taking the 'no spaces around the variable assignments' part of the fix as given.

Using array notation seems like overkill.  Allowing for possible spaces in names, you can use:

```
for dir in "$TRACE" "$LFPS" "$NOTES" "$PASS"
do mkdir "$dir"
done
```

But even that is wasteful:

```
mkdir "$TRACE" "$LFPS" "$NOTES" "$PASS"
```

If you're worried that the directories might exist, you can avoid error messages for that with:

```
mkdir -p "$TRACE" "$LFPS" "$NOTES" "$PASS"
```

The `-p` option is also valuable if the paths are longer and some of the intermediate directories might be missing.  If you're sure there won't be spaces in the names, the double quotes become optional (but they're safe and cheap, so you might as well use them).

Comment: This is a smart solution, I didn't even realize you could pass multiple parameters to `mkdir`.

Comment: in the last 2 examples, I found the that I had to remove the dollar ($) sign for bash to interpret the command properly.

Comment: @Paul: Without seeing exactly what you typed, it's impossible to guess what you're doing wrong. However, if the variables are set up (as in the question), then the `$` signs before the variable names are correct and necessary; without them, the directories created would have names `TRACE`, `LFPS`, `NOTES`, `PASS` rather than `/Traces`, `/LFPS`, `/Notes`, … whatever is in `$PASS`. The names with the leading slashes have another set of problems; you don't usually go creating directories under `/` unless you're logged in as `root`. If you can create them, you've got problems — that are fixable.

Answer (score 3):

Also you would want to do some checking beforehand if folders exist or not. 
Also you can always debug the shell script with set -x, you could just use "mkdir -p" which would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I made the following changes to get your script to run.

As a review comment it is unusual to create such folders hanging off the root file system.

```
#!/bin/sh
TRACES="/Traces"
LFPS='/LFPS'
ANALYSIS='/Analysis'
NOTES='/Notes'
SPIKES='/Spikes'

folders="$TRACES $LFPS $ANALYSIS $NOTES $SPIKES"
for folder in $folders
do
   mkdir $folder
done
```

Spaces were removed from the initial variable assignments and I also simplified the for loop so that it iterated over the words in the `folders` string.

Comment: Would be better to loop over the elements of the array, if you only left the array (now how can we deal with potential spaces in file names?). Besides, a loop is useless, `mkdir $folders` is plenty enough.

Comment: I agree. That was a quick hack. I rarely consider spaces in directory file names in a Unix/Unix-like OS setting because like Rocky Balboa and condominiums, I never use them ;-) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSGweaROZBQ

Comment: +1 for "Do not create folders like that in the root directory".